# Amazon reviews web scraping in R: how to avoid running into an error, when one of the reviews is from another country?

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

In order to get some interesting data for NLP, I just started to do some basic web scraping in R. My goal is to gather product reviews from amazon, as much as I can. My first basic trials succeeded, but now I am running into an error.

As you can check from the url in my reprex, there are 3 pages of reviews for the product. If I scrape the first and second one, everything works fine. The third page contains a review from a foreign customer.

When I am trying to scrape page three I am getting an error indicating, that my tibble columns do not have compatible sizes. How can I explain this and how to avoid the error?

Also the error disappears, if I delete review_star and review_title from the scrape function.

```
library(pacman)
pacman::p_load(RCurl, XML, dplyr, rvest)

#### SCRAPE

scrape_amazon <- function(page_num){
  
  url_reviews <- paste0("https://www.amazon.de/Lavendel-%C3%96L-Fein-kbA-%C3%84therisch/product-reviews/B00EXBKQDS/ref=cm_cr_getr_d_paging_btm_next_3?ie=UTF8&reviewerType=all_reviews&pageNumber=",page_num)
  doc <- read_html(url_reviews) 
  # Review Title
  doc %>% 
    html_nodes("[class='a-size-base a-link-normal review-title a-color-base review-title-content a-text-bold']") %>%
    html_text() -> review_title
  # Review Text
  doc %>% 
    html_nodes("[class='a-size-base review-text review-text-content']") %>%
    html_text() -> review_text
  # Number of stars in review
  doc %>%
    html_nodes("[data-hook='review-star-rating']") %>%
    html_text() -> review_star
  # date
  date <- doc %>%
    html_nodes("#cm_cr-review_list .review-date") %>%
    html_text() %>% 
    gsub(".*on ", "", .)
  # author
  author <- doc %>%
    html_nodes("#cm_cr-review_list .a-profile-name") %>%
    html_text()
  
  # Return a tibble
  tibble(review_title,
         review_text,
         review_star,
         date,
         author,
         page = page_num) %>% return()
}

# extract testing
df <- scrape_amazon(page_num = 3)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, a couple of approaches I generally use in situations concerning listings where some listings may have missing items/differences in html:

1. Find a css selector list which returns the listings as an iterable (list of listings). In this case `[id^='customer_review']` can be used. If you test this in the browser dev tools you can check the number of matches. This should be a parent node list containing all the items (per listing) you want.
2. Loop that list within a nested `map_dfr(), data.frame()` call and target the various child nodes such that a) you get a dataframe b) you get a nice NA returned for missing items.
3. Use dev tools <kbd>F12</kbd> to check that the lengths of returned nodeLists, per css selector list, to get an idea of where items may be missing e.g.

Your rating selector against page 3:

[image]

which misses the difference in HTML for non-Germany based listings

```
data-hook="cmps-review-star-rating"
```

Compare that to testing in advance and re-writing as:

[image]

N.B. 1) There is a leading id selector in the list in the image serving to restrict to the same nodeList that we would be iterating over i.e. excluding the Top +ve and Top critical review items 2) The html content returned by rvest will be as per the page source rather than the browser rendered content so it is worth then doing a secondary check of your selectors against that content. I typically use Fetch URL within [jsoup](https://try.jsoup.org/) via the online interactive demo tool (though you might prefer something like Postman where you can more easily test other request aspects e.g. headers.

> jsoup is a Java library for working with real-world HTML. It provides
> a very convenient API for fetching URLs and extracting and
> manipulating data, using the best of HTML5 DOM methods and CSS
> selectors.

With FF you also seem to get a handy dandy dropdown to assist with selecting child DOM elements:

[image]

4. As shown below, prefer shorter css selector lists, with more stable looking relationships/attributes, to mitigate for changes in html over time

TODO: There are some type conversions you may wish to implement as an immediate item

---

```
library(pacman)
pacman::p_load(RCurl, XML, dplyr, rvest, purrr)

#### SCRAPE

scrape_amazon <- function(page_num) {
  url_reviews <- paste0("https://www.amazon.de/Lavendel-%C3%96L-Fein-kbA-%C3%84therisch/product-reviews/B00EXBKQDS/ref=cm_cr_getr_d_paging_btm_next_3?ie=UTF8&reviewerType=all_reviews&pageNumber=", page_num)
  doc <- read_html(url_reviews)

  map_dfr(doc %>% html_elements("[id^='customer_review']"), ~ data.frame(
    review_title = .x %>% html_element(".review-title") %>% html_text2(),
    review_text = .x %>% html_element(".review-text-content") %>% html_text2(),
    review_star = .x %>% html_element(".review-rating") %>% html_text2(),
    date = .x %>% html_element(".review-date") %>% html_text2() %>% gsub(".*vom ", "", .),
    author = .x %>% html_element(".a-profile-name") %>% html_text2(),
    page = page_num
  )) %>%
    as_tibble %>%
    return()
}

# extract testing
df <- scrape_amazon(page_num = 3)
# df <- scrape_amazon(page_num = 2)
```

---

[image]